# Wifi network not picked up by specific device

Tags: wireless-networking, router, windows-8.1

I have a [Zyxel NBG-416N](http://www.zyxel.com/products_services/nbg_416n.shtml?t=p) router, which randomly stopped working on my PC that is running 64-bit Windows 8.1. 
Strange thing is that while the PC can't pick up my particular home network, it finds all other networks around me.

Another strange thing is that my phone, tablet and other PCs can find and connect to the network without any problems.

Here's what I've tried so far to fix the problem, with no result:

- Plugging it out and back in
- Restarting the PC and router
- Reinstalling the PCs network drivers
- Reinstalling/Reseting the router's firmware
- Changing the network ID and password
- Running the Windows troubleshooters
- Disabling and re-enabling the WiFi adapter from the control panel
- "Forgetting" the network from the settings
- Banging my head against the wall

Is there something else I could try in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure the Wi-Fi AP is set to use a channel supported by the client machine. For example, North American (FCC) equipment only supports channels 1-11 in 2.4GHz, whereas European (ETSI) equipment can support channels 1-13. If you somehow got an ETSI AP but an FCC client adapter, then if the AP uses channel 12 or 13, your client adapter might not be able to connect. This tends to be less of a problem nowadays than it used to be, because modern client adapters will adopt the ETSI channel set if they see they're around ETSI APs, but maybe you have a cheap client adapter that doesn't do that.
- Make sure you're not running into interference problems on your PC. If your client adapter is a USB dongle, try putting it at the end of a USB extender cable (or on a small USB hub at the end of a USB cable, and move it away from your PC case and monitor, in case either of those is emitting interference on some part of the 2.4GHz band.
- Make sure that the AP is set to broadcast its SSID. That is, make sure it's not doing a "hidden" network. Not broadcasting your SSID doesn't really help security, but it can definitely cause hassles getting clients connected to your network.
- If you're using wireless security on your Wi-Fi AP, make sure it's set to WPA2 (AES-CCMP). Earlier schemes like WPA[1] (TKIP) and WEP aren't fast enough for 802.11n. Your AP is not really 802.11n-compliant if you have WPA or WEP enabled without WPA2.
- Make sure you have WMM (QoS) enabled. 802.11n compliance requires WMM. I wouldn't be surprised if some clients choke when they see a network that claims to be 802.11n but doesn't do WMM.

Comment: Thank you @Spiff! Had to poke around the channels a bit, but turns out that anything below 12 works fine. Although its a bit strange considering that the device was purchased in Europe.